# how to use for each in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

```
***I have a xml ---***
<DBOperation>
<ListOfOperation>
<operation>
<operationName>Insert</operationName>
<input>
<empid>3</empid>
<name>saurabh</name>
</input>
<operationName>Delete</operationName>
<input>
<empid>3</empid>
</input>
<operationName>insert</operationName>
<empid>3</empid>
<name>saurabh</name>
<operationName>update</operationName>
<input>
<empid>3</empid>
<name>raj</>
</input>
</operation>
</ListOfOperation>
</DBOperation>
```

I want to send this xml as a soap message but the entire operation at once such that using one request i can perform all the operations using choice routing....what is the most effecient method to do this in **mulesoft**...and if using for each what should be my **collection tab configuration**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<flow name="dbopps">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration1" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
***<foreach collection="#[xpath://.[xpath:local-name()='DBOperation']/*[xpath:local-name()='ListOfOperation']/*[xpath:local-name()='operation']]" doc:name="For Each" >***
<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
<logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-variable variableName="name" value="#[xpath('//operationName').text]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<logger message="#[flowVars.name]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<choice tracking:enable-default-events="true" doc:name="Choice">
<when expression="#[flowVars.name == 'Insert']">
<db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Insert">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[Insert into employees(empid,name) values ('43',#[xpath('//name').text])]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:insert>
</when>
<when expression="#[flowVars.name == 'Delete']">
<db:delete config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Delete">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[Delete from employees where empid='10']]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:delete>
</when>
</foreach>
<set-variable variableName="id" value="#[xpath://.[xpath:local-name()='DBOperation']/*[xpath:local-name()='ListOfOperation']/*[xpath:local-name()='operation']/*[xpath:local-name()='operationName']']" doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-payload value="&lt;a&gt; hello &lt;/a&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

This works fine for me you can check the collection tab configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need create a webservice that returns this xml as response?

If yes, This might help you:

JAVA (NO MULE)

- Create a java bean and properties that match exactly with your xml : Response.java
- Create a java class with one operation, that return this Response. And using some library, create your webservice:

```
 

@WebService

    public class WebService {       
        public Response operation_name(Request request){

        }
    }
```

Request class if you need some parameter.

https://github.com/jrichardsz/java-web-services-template-soa-rest

- Finally when you need return xml as response, use a unmarshall process to convert your xml file to Response.java.

http://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-unmarshalling-example

MULE

- I think are the same steps because Mule can create a web service from a java class:
  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/building-web-services-with-cxf

Regards